# why does hotspot jvm use extern "C" in its JNI modules?

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

Since jvm itself is implemented and built by c++, why does it need to declare extern "C"?

extern "C" is used to generated c-compatible target, why does a c++ jvm need that?

Comment: Because JNI is intended for use from any language and the C++ ABI is a mess, but almost all languages have good support for the C ABI.

Comment: @PiRocks is that true? I thought JNI mechanism is just used by jvm itself. Can you provide any document or example that other language uses JNIs?

Comment: @scottxiao -- just do a Google search for "JNI".

Comment: The C ABI is the binary *lingua franca* across many languages.  The C++ ABI is... the opposite.

Comment: @Eljay unbelievable, what kind of language excep c/c++ uses C ABI？

Comment: @scottxiao • Java for one, that's what JNI uses.

Comment: You can use the invocation API ( https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html) to create a JVM from any language that has a foreign function interface (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface). Well, technically you could use any exported function in a library, but with those created from C++ that's much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice quality of JNI is that you can compile it once and link it to any JVM for that platform. These days that's less of an issue since pretty much all JVMs are based on OpenJDK, but once upon a time there were several JVMs that had completely different implementations. My JNI library compiled on Windows could link to the Sun JVM or the Microsoft JVM. Using "C" linkage ensures compatibility regardless of what compiler I'm using, or what compiler the JVM was built with. The names won't get mangled, the parameters aren't modified, etc.

Comment: Minor nit on my answer: The Microsoft JVM never supported JNI. Other JVMs did.